# OnePair Pokerhand method java

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out why my code isn't working. trying to create a pokerhand program for school and am trying to write the one pair method. I have to return a boolean. not sure why the count variable returns such a high value if I my array has numbers 2,2,3,4,5.

```
public static boolean containsPair(int [] hand)  
{
  boolean pair = false;
  int count = 1;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    for(int j = 1; j < 5; j++)
    {
      if (hand[i] == hand[j])
      count++;

    }

  }
  System.out.println(count);
  if (count == 2)
  pair = true;
  return pair;
```

Comment: Because you're comparing one card with itself when `i` and `j` are same value.

Answer (score 2):

In your 2 nested `for` loops, you are counting the cases where `i == j`, so that each card equals itself.  Start `j` from one past wherever `i` is:

```
for(int j = i + 1; j < 5; j++)
```

This way, you don't make comparisons twice and you don't compare the card with itself.  You are now only comparing a card with all the cards past that card.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically comparing all the cards with all the other cards. For example both i and j will be 4 at some point.  So `if (hand[i] == hand[j])` will be true when `i==j`.

Also, you adding up the values for all the cards, you need to reset it after each card (after each iteration of the first for loop).

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
   count = 1;
   for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
   {
      if ((i != j) && (hand[i] == hand[j]))
         count++;
   }
   if (count == 2)
       pair = true;
 }
```

Of course this will return true if there are two pairs, so you will have to account for that too.

Edit: @rgettman's is right, you can start use his for loop to remove duplicates and get rid of the `i!=j` check.  You still need to reset count for each card though, and still need to do something to check for two pairs. It should be easy to make this method look for both one and two pairs in a general fashion since you will need to do that too.

Comment: You rearranged the overall structure of the code! If the OP only adjusts the `j` loop and counts total coincidences, then `count == 2` will correspond to two pairs *only*; three of a kind will produce `count == 3`, four of a kind `count == 6`and full house `count == 4`. The intended pair function should check `count == 1` instead. (So we see that many other poker hands can be detected with essetnialla the same function - the OP may wish to tr a modular approach)